# How can I use regex to replace a character in part of a string

Tags: regex, sed, replace, splunk

I have the following string:

```
  This is part 1: and this is part 2
```

The string starts with 2 spaces, has an part before the separator ":" and a part after the separator.

I want to replace every space before the separator, except the spaces at the beginning of the line, with an underscore and leave the spaces after the separator.

The end result should look like this:

```
  This_is_part_1: and this is part 2
```

The part before the separator is of variable length and has a variable number of spaces.

This regex will be used in Splunk which uses a sed based replacement mechanism.

Is what I want at all possible and if so, how?

Comment: How interesting. Why would someone down vote a question without adding a remark to explain the reasoning behind the down vote? A remark would help the person who asks the question to improve the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
\b(\s)+(?=.*:)
```

It seems that this works.

```
  This is part 1: and this is part 2
```

replace with "_"

```
  This_is_part_1: and this is part 2
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/6)

**Edited**

Above regex replaces consecutive spaces to one underscore.

If you want replace consecutive spaces to consecutive underscore as 1 to 1, must use another regex like follows

```
(?<=\b|(?<!^)(?<!^\s))(\s)(?=.*:)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/7)

Comment: Thanx, I'll try your suggestion out and will let you know my results!

Comment: In your question, spaces in the string are all one character length, so the above answer will work. But if consecutive spaces which is longer than 2 characters exist in the string, above regex replaces consecutive spaces to one underscore. If you want replace consecutive spaces to consecutive underscore, must use another regex like this..  (?<=\b|(?<!^)(?<!^\s))(\s)(?=.*:)  https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/7